# BehaviourSubject and CombineLatest - Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In the following code:

```
public class Connection
{
    private BehaviorSubject<string> addressSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("null");
    private EventLoopScheduler scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts));
    private IDisposable reconnectSubscription = null;

    public Connection()
    {
        this.reconnectSubscription = this.addressSubject
            .ObserveOn(this.scheduler)
            .CombineLatest(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), this.scheduler), (x, y) => x)
            .Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
    }    

    public void Connect(string address)
    {
        Observable.Start(() => this.addressSubject.OnNext(address), this.scheduler);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Observable.Start(() => this.addressSubject.OnNext(null), this.scheduler);
    }
}
```

After calling ´Connect´ it prints.

```
null
localhost
null
localhost
null
localhost
```

I think it is some threading issues, since if I call `Connect` in the constructor it works as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried your code with no changes and it worked fine for me. I'm using version 1.1.10621 of Rx.

Comment: Your use of a `Connect`/`Disconnect` pair of methods isn't very Rx-ish. Also the use of `Observable.Start` isn't really the correct way to use it. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Instead of Debug.WriteLine it will call a method `DoConnect`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: In what way am I misusing `Observable.Start`? Also I guess it's not rly needed here, I was just not sure about threading issues, whether `BehaviourSubject` is thread-safe.

Comment: `Observable.Start` is used to define an observable to subscribe to. If you're just triggering a action on another thread try `ThreadPoolScheduler.Schedule`.